# Javascript: Double clicking link hides element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to Javascript and am piecing together code I found from earlier forums to assemble what I have. I am currently working on a sizing chart that has the options of viewing the inches and centimeters version. I was able to get the two separate charts to view correctly when clicking on the Inches and Centimeters links... BUT when you are viewing the table and click on the corresponding link, it will collapse. I sincerely appreciate any direction!

```
var divs = ["Inches", "Centimeters"];
var visibleDivId = null;
function divVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }
  hideNonVisibleDivs(divId);
}
function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;
  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);
    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the div you have clicked is current `visibleDivId`, you are setting `visibleDivId` to null and hiding all divs whose value does not match the `visibleDivId` (which is true for all divs because your `visibleDivId` is `null` and none of your divs are `null`), so all divs are getting hidden.

**Fix:** Don't set `visibleDivId` to `null`, when the div you clicked on is same as `visibleDivId`. In fact you don't need to do anything in that case.

This should work perfectly

```
var divs = ["Inches", "Centimeters"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function divVisibility(divId) {
    if (visibleDivId !== divId) {
        visibleDivId = divId;
        hideNonVisibleDivs();
    }
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
    var i, divId, div;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if (visibleDivId === divId) {
            div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I sincerely appreciate this! You nailed it!